# Calculate All Sides and Angles from Area, One Side, and Adjacent angle of triangle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I have one Area of Triangle, One adjacent angle, and one side. Is it possible to calculate all other sides and angles ?

I have searched this problem, but could not get any reference to it.

Comment: If I get the problem correctly, yes. You can first find the altitude with respect to the given side. Then divide by the sine of the given angle to get the side adjacent to the given angle. And from there it should be almost done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $a$ and $b$ are two sides of the triangle and $\gamma$ is the angle in between then its Area is
$$\text{Area}=\frac{a\cdot b\cdot\sin(\gamma)}{2}\implies b=\frac{2\cdot \text{Area}}{a\cdot \sin(\gamma)}$$
and we find another side. For the third side use the [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) or the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) and finally find the remaining angles from the [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sin).
Can you take it from here?

Comment: how can i get the second angle from there? 

Sorry, but i am just very basic to this math.

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar See my edit.

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: this one helped.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose in $\triangle ABC$ that the known angle is $A$ and the adjacent known side is $b$. We can get the altitude $h_c$ from vertex $C$ onto $AB$ as
$$h_c=b\sin A$$
The length of $AB$, or $c$, can now be determined as $\frac{2\operatorname{Area}(ABC)}{h_c}$. Now two sides and the included angle are known, so the rest is easy.